# Correlation of multiple values across years and strata

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Year   Strata  Value1    Value2
1999       1   44268     0.8725
1999       2   46009     1.4550
1999       3   27715     3.1100
2000       1   24015     1.5800
2000       2   55601     1.5400
2000       3   15765     3.3200
```

I'm looking to find if value1 is correlated with value2, across years and strata. The real dataframe has many more years than this.

The repeated measure needs to be year, and it needs to be blocked by strata.

How is this done using R? Do you need to use aov()?

Comment: When you say **blocked** by strata, do you mean **grouped** by strata?

Comment: Yes I guess that would be the same thing.

Comment: You can probably do something like this. `library(plyr); ddply(df, .(Strata), summarize, corCoeff = cor(Value1, Value2))`

Comment: I don't believe that accounts for year though

Comment: If you are just doing measurement over `year` variable and trying to find the correlation between `Value1` and `Value2`, then what `year` should not matter, does it? Or are you trying to find the correlation within each year also? It doesn't seem like you have enough observations within each year unless this is just part of your data?

Comment: If you do want to explore by year also, you can simply add the variable into the group parenthesis as `ddply(df, .(Year, Strata), summarize, corCoeff = cor(Value1, Value2))`